# Enter DateTime value from one form to another form in TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, textbox, datetimepicker

Okay I have three forms. In `Form1` I have 2 `dateTimePicker` and 1 button. When I click that button I go to `Form2` which has another button. When I click that button it shows a message giving the value of `dateTimePicker`. I have another `Form3` where I have a textbox.

Question: So instead of showing the value in message in Form 2, what I want is that when I select a value in dateTimePicker in Form1 and click the btn, Form2 should open and in the form2 when i click the button form3 should open and in the textBox in Form3 dateTimePicker value should be displayed.
This is what I have so far.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //form1
    {
        Form2 obj = new Form2(textBox1.Text,dateTimePicker1.Value,dateTimePicker2.Value);
        this.Hide();
        obj.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();

        Form3 f3 = new Form3(dateTimePicker1.Value);
    }

    string Name; //form2
    DateTime DT1;
    DateTime DT2;
    DateTime DT3;
    public Form2(string name, DateTime dt1,DateTime dt2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Name = name;
        DT1 = dt1;
        DT2 = dt2;
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Check In Date: "+ DT1.ToString() + " Check Out Date: " + DT2.ToString());
        Form3 f3 = new Form3(DT1);
        f3.ShowDialog();
    }

    DateTime ChkInDate; // form3
    public Form3(DateTime chkindate)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChkInDate = chkindate;
    }

    private void CheckInTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckInTxt.Text = ChkInDate.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The code in CheckInTxt_TextChanged does not make sense.
Where exaclty is your problem?

Comment: Yeah i removed that part. all I wanted was to display DateTime in my Form3 textBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the initial value of the TextBox in Form3's constructor.

```
public Form3(DateTime chkindate)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ChkInDate = chkindate;
    CheckInTxt.Text = chkindate.ToString(); // add this line
}
```

Comment: Also remove CheckInTxt_TextChanged

Comment: Thank you so much. I finally got it.

Comment: @samjohal, Please mark it as answer if it helps, thank you. you can format it like `ToString("dd MM yyyy")`, it will display day month year